# How to add keys and values to an array the simplest way

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to know the simplest way to add the value of the 
$titles->post_title to become the key and value of an array.

Here is my code:

```
$data_from_database = array();

$titles = get_posts( array( 

        'post_type' => 'resort',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ) ); 

foreach($data_from_database as $field_key => $field_value) {
    $field['choices'][$field_key] = $field_value;
    $field['choices'][$field_value] = $field_value;
}
```

Desired result:

```
 $data_from_database = array('1value' => '1value', '2value' => '2value', 
 '3value' => '3value');
```

I have looked and read other posts about this but wasnt able to find any info to achieved what i want to do.

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: Why did you tag this with Javascript? Your code is PHP, not Javascript.

Comment: If i understand you can do this  $field['choices'][$field_value] = $field_value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys..

I figured it out by using this code.

```
$data_from_database = array();

  $myarray = array();

    $titles = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'resort') ); 

    $new_title = wp_list_pluck($titles, 'post_title', 'post_title');


// reset choices
$field['choices'] = array();


// if has rows
 foreach($new_title as $field_key => $field_value) {
    $field['choices'][$field_key] = $field_value;
}


// return the field
return $field;
```

wordpress has a built in function to automatically push values and keys to an array

Answer (score 0):

Your question is completely unclear so try to add more details to get  more complete answers.However based on you desired output

> ```
> $data_from_database = array('1value' => '1value', '2value' => '2value', 
>  '3value' => '3value');
> ```

and this:

> I would like to know the simplest way to add the value of the
>   $titles->post_title to become the key and value of an array.

you can alter your code to look like this:

```
$data_from_database = array();

$titles = get_posts( array( 

        'post_type' => 'resort',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ) ); 

foreach($titles as $field_key => $field_value) {
    $data_from_database[$field_key] = $field_key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get your desired output

```
$data_from_database = array();

$titles = get_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'order' => 'ASC'
) ); 

foreach($titles as $value) {
  $data_from_database[$value->post_title] = $value->post_title;
}
```

Hope this helps you.